# Error establishing database connection - PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been using PDO for years but never got into this problem before.

I have this code in my **dbconnector.php** file.

```
<?php
$connectionString = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb';
try
{
    $conn = new PDO($connectionString, 'myuser', 'mypass');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
var_dump($conn);
?>
```

If I run this file directly, I get this output :-

```
object(PDO)#1 (0) { }
```

However, if I run any file which has this dbconnector file included in it, I get this :-

```
object(PDO)#1 (0) { } SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1651 Query cache is disabled; restart the server with query_cache_type=1 to enable it

Error establishing a database connection
```

Why am I getting this and how could I fix it?

Comment: Doesn't the error message already tell you what to fix?

Comment: @mario

So I fixed the Error establishing thingy, but the General error still remains. I do not have access to mysql command line. How do I fix it?

Comment: Ask your hosting provider. Else: try `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` as init option.